# JPA Entities Generating Wrong Database Design

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

In my project, an Admin (User) can set to receive scheduled emails about any User he chooses.

I need to have a database of the following design:

```
TABLE User (
    UserId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Email VARCHAR,
    FirstName VARCHAR,
    LastName VARCHAR
    IsAdmin BOOL,
    ...
)

TABLE Email_Schedule (
    ScheduleId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, /* this is not necessary */
    AdminId INT, /* could be replaced by a composite foreign primary keys */
    UserId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (AdminId) REFERENCES User (UserId),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES User (UserId)
)
```

The following code in my Java classes for JPA entity:

```
@Entity
public class Email_Schedule {
   @Id
   private int scheduleId;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
   private List<User> admins = new LinkedList<>();

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
   private List<User> users = new LinkedList<>();

   public Email_Schedule() {
    super();
   }

   public Email_Schedule(User admin, User user) {
      super();
      this.admins.add(admin);
      this.users.add(user);
   }
   // setters and getters...
```

generates a database of the following schema:

```
 TABLE USER (
     ...
 )
 TABLE SCHEDULE (
     ScheduleId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
 )
 TABLE Email_Schedule (
     ScheduleId INT,
     Users INT,
     Admins INT,
     FOREIGN KEY (ScheduleId) REFERENCES SCHEDULE(ScheduleId),
     FOREIGN KEY (Users) REFERENCES USER (UserId),
     FOREIGN KEY (Admins) REFERENCES USER (UserId)
 )
```

My question is why did it create a useless table for `ScheduleId` and referenced it from another table instead of just using it directly in `Email_Schedule` table?

The problem seems to be with the `ScheduleId`.. I tried not to use it by creating `IdClass` but I got different errors and wrong database designs.

Comment: Which tool did you use for ddl generation?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Eclipse, JPA Tool, Generate Tables from Entities. Then, I checked the generated tables in MySQL workbench.

Comment: Could you try with using hbm2ddl directly?

Comment: well actually I'm not using Hibernate, I'm using EclipseLink

Comment: IMHO, your design mistake relates to list structures, an object (instance) of type Email_Schedule should have a one-to-one (one-to-many) relationship to a user and admin.

Comment: Not sure whether @GeneratedValue is needed for scheduleId

Comment: @home  there are different admins and each admin can set his own schedules with certain users.

Comment: @WandMaker I tried with and without `@GeneratedValue` and the result is the same..

Comment: See if you can share User entity's code as well

Comment: @rz3r0: but the requirements on top of your question forbid this approach. It defines one scheduleId per user and admin.

Comment: @home, the `scheduleId` is not necessary. I can replace it with composite primary foreign key for `adminId` and `userId` that both reference User (userId)

Comment: @home  EDIT: you are right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EclipseLink is using `TABLE` for generating sequence for `scheduleId`.
This seems to be the default.

> You can use a table for identifier generation on any database. This
>   strategy is completely portable across databases and *will be
>   automatically generated for you when schema generation is enabled*.

As per [EclipseLink](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey) Documentation, you may have to use generation strategy of `IDENTITY` for `scheduleId` to avoid the `TABLE` appraoch.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Note that if you use `AUTO` strategy as shown below, then, even in that case, EclipseLink may pick `TABLE` strategy for ID generation.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

> **Using a Default Generation Strategy**
>
> Specifying a strategy of AUTO
>   allows EclipseLink to select the strategy to use. Typically,
>   EclipseLink picks TABLE as the strategy, since it is the most portable
>   strategy. However, when AUTO is specified, schema generation must be
>   used at least once in order for the default table to be created in the
>   database.

More details here at [PrimaryKey](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey) and [GeneratedValue](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/GeneratedValue) Documentation

Comment: can you suggest an answer that doesn't use scheduleId?

Comment: What database you are using?  Do you specify a value for eclipselink.target-database ?

Comment: I'm using MySQL, and no I don't use `target-database`

Comment: The WandMaker answer looks fine. rz3r0 did you try so set eclipselink.ddl-generation property? Maybe it is not replacing the tables thar already exsitis, use drop-and-create-tables strategy, for more details see http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation.htm

Comment: Also try using <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/> to ensure tables are MySQL friendly.   Unfortunately, I am not setup to test out your scenario as I am not using EclipseLink in my projects.

Comment: @Guillermo well, it's not working! I even tried adding dumb fields to check if it dropping tables before creating them and it is...

Comment: @Guillermo well, you were right! it wasn't dropping "ALL" tables... thank you. And yes, WandMaker solution was right!